# Add total from rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the total of values in the table below but with some conditions which i dont know how to implement

```
<table id="tableID" width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="compulsory">5</td>
    <td class="compulsory">8</td>
    <td class="compulsory">8</td>

    <td class="one">8</td>
    <td class="one">7</td>
    <td class="one">6</td>

    <td class="two">9</td>
    <td class="two">4</td>

    <td class="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The conditions are;

> Table data  with class **compulsory** must be added
>
> Table data  with class **one** pick the highest two values
>
> Table data  with class **two** pick the highest one value

Then display the total in the Table data  with class **total**

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. You are expected to show code you have used to attempt to solve problem yourself and people here help you make that code work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about below solution, you can refactor further if needed.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table border="1" id="tableID" width="200">
        <tr>
            <td class="compulsory">5</td>
            <td class="compulsory">8</td>
            <td class="compulsory">8</td>
            <td class="one">8</td>
            <td class="one">7</td>
            <td class="one">6</td>
            <td class="two">9</td>
            <td class="two">4</td>
            <td class="total"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
var tdsCompulsory = tr.getElementsByClassName('compulsory');
var tdsOne = document.getElementsByClassName('one');
var tdsTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('two');

var cData = [];
var oneData = [];
var twoData = [];
var sum = 0;

for(var i in tdsCompulsory){
    if(typeof tdsCompulsory[i].textContent != 'undefined')
    cData.push(tdsCompulsory[i].textContent);
}
for(var i in tdsOne){
    if(typeof tdsOne[i].textContent != 'undefined')
    oneData.push(tdsOne[i].textContent);
}
for(var i in tdsTwo){
    if(typeof tdsTwo[i].textContent != 'undefined')
    twoData.push(tdsTwo[i].textContent);
}
console.log(cData);
console.log(oneData);
console.log(twoData);

for(var i in cData){
    sum +=parseInt(cData[i]);
}

var maxOne=0, maxTwo=0;
for(var i in oneData){
        if(maxOne < parseInt(oneData[i])){
            maxTwo = maxOne;
            maxOne = parseInt(oneData[i]);
        } else if(maxTwo < parseInt(oneData[i])){
            maxTwo = parseInt(oneData[i]);
        }
}
sum += maxOne + maxTwo;

var max = 0;
for(var i in twoData){
    if(max < parseInt(twoData[i])){
        max = parseInt(twoData[i]);
    }
}
console.log(max);    
sum +=max;
console.log(sum);    
document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].textContent = sum;
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with @Yosel's code is that he is summing up all of the values. Your conditions are to sum up all the values in the first group, the top 2 in the second and the highest in the third.

This will yield a total of 45.

This would be a lot easier with jQuery, but the question is tagged JavaScript, so I added a JS only solution.

Start by querying all the elements of a collection with `querySelectorAll`. Initialize a sum variable that will keep track of the total.

The first group is easy, we can just add all the items together. Since HTML collections do not have access to all array methods, we need to create separate arrays to store the values.

In your example, the values are conveniently sorted, but we cannot always assume this is the case. Run the `sort` function to be on the safe side. To get the first two values, the `slice` function can be used.

Iterate over the largest two numbers that we just found and add the value to our sum. The third one is a bit easier, since we can just use the `max` function

```js
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");

/* we have three seperate groups. Because each has a different condition, we have to create three separate variables.*/
var compulsory = document.querySelectorAll(".compulsory");
var one = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
var two = document.querySelectorAll(".two");

var sum = 0;                     // Store the running total

for (var i = 0; i < compulsory.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(compulsory[i].innerHTML);
}

/* QuerySelectorAll returns a collection, so we can't use the sort method on it. Have to create new array objects. */
var oneValues = []; var twoValues = [];

for (var i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
    oneValues.push(parseInt(one[i].innerHTML));
}

/* Can't assume numbers will always be in order. Sort by descending first and then take the first two numbers */
oneValues = oneValues.sort((a,b) => b - a).slice(0,2);

// Sum up these two numbers;
for (var i = 0; i < oneValues.length; i++) {
    sum += oneValues[i];
}

for (var i = 0; i < two.length; i++) {
    twoValues.push(parseInt(two[i].innerHTML));
}

sum += Math.max.apply(Math, twoValues);

document.getElementsByClassName("total")[0].innerHTML = sum;
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.total {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableID" width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Compulsory</td>
    <td class="compulsory">5</td>
    <td class="compulsory">8</td>
    <td class="compulsory">8</td>

    <td>One</td>
    <td class="one">8</td>
    <td class="one">7</td>
    <td class="one">6</td>

    <td>Two</td>
    <td class="two">9</td>
    <td class="two">4</td>
     <td>Total</td>
    <td class="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow great. Do you also have the jquery version?

Comment: I can't add it because the question is not tagged jquery

Comment: @RichardHamilton I have updated my answer based on the question.. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using jQuery:

```js
var total = 0,
    oneVal = 0,
    twoVal = 0,
    one = [],
    two = [],
    $tds = $('td:not(:last-child)');

$tds.each(function(i) {
    var currentClass = $(this).attr('class'),
        currentVal = parseInt($(this).html());
  
    switch (currentClass) {        
        case 'one':
            one.push(currentVal);
            break;

        case 'two':
            two.push(currentVal);
            break;
        
        default:
          total += currentVal;
    }

    if (i + 1 === $tds.length) {
        // Sort and sum the big ones
        one.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
        oneVal = one[one.length - 1] + one[one.length - 2];

        // Get the max
        twoVal = Math.max.apply(Math, two);
          
        total = total + oneVal + twoVal;
    } 
});

$('td.total').html(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableID" width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="compulsory">5</td>
    <td class="compulsory">8</td>
    <td class="compulsory">8</td>

    <td class="one">8</td>
    <td class="one">7</td>
    <td class="one">6</td>

    <td class="two">9</td>
    <td class="two">4</td>

    <td class="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't filter the conditions in question

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated my answer based on the question.. Thanks for the comment!